# Returning value (Int) from Kotlin coroutine from Java call

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've been struggling to return a value from a Kotlin coroutine back to Java for what feels like way too long.  This is how I finally got it to work, but am not 100% sure that it is the best way.  The ways I get a return value **when returning to Kotlin** are not working.  I'm simply updating the UI with the total row count in the SQLite db.

Here's my call from Java (activity) from main thread

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(DbUtil.getDbRowCount()));
```

And here's the method in DbUtil (Kotlin object Class)

```
@JvmStatic
fun getDbRowCount(): Int = runBlocking {
    withContext(IO){DbHelper.getInstance().dbRowCount}
}
```

My questions:

1. Does adding the withContext(IO) keep the main thread from being blocked?
2. If this does in fact block, how can I rewrite this so that it doesn't.

Comment: > It works, but is this OK?, It won't have any effect of dispatching it to the IO pool, it will going to block the calling thread, and it seems you are changing the value of a UI element so you are most probably calling it from the Main thread, so it might give choppy experience as main thread will be blocked till function returns.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu see my additional edit

Answer (score 3):

Using runBlocking does what it says, blocks for the result. So dispatching to the IO dispatcher has no effect.

A suspending function can only be callable by a coroutine, so you must be inside a coroutine in order to call any suspendable function.

1. First to remove the barrier, i.e. to make the function callable from non-coroutine body:

```kotlin
@JvmStatic
val scope = CoroutineScope(EmptyCoroutineContext)

@JvmStatic
fun getDbRowCount(): Deferred<Int> = scope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
    DbHelper.getInstance().dbRowCount
}
```

If you are on a coroutine (in Kotlin code) you can simply call `.await()` to get Int result (suspending).

2. To make the result interoperable with Java, you can convert the Deferred from the coroutine to a CompletableFuture.

```java
// requires: latest $version as of now is 1.3.9
// implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:$version"
CompletableFuture cf = FutureKt.asCompletableFuture(getDbRowCount());
```

3. Then you can use the callback-style to listen to the result:

```java
cf.whenCompleteAsync((result, exception) -> {
    // Ensure UI change happens on Main/UI thread.
    new Handler(context.getMainLooper()).post(() -> tv.setText(String.valueOf(result)));
});
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'FutureKt'.   I do have latest dependencies

Comment: @seekingStillness It is bundled in `kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8 package`, not available in `core` package by default.